# Android update user after login by using volley

Tags: java, php, android

I'm currently having trouble of updating a user profile after they have login. The table i have is different but is linked together, which mean i get the `Username` from another table and update the `profile details` on another table. Here is my php and java file. Additionally, i'm not really good at  android and php coding, any guidance will be much appreciated!

**UpdateProfile.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if( !empty( $_POST ) )
{

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "users");

$Username = $_POST['Username'];
$Dri_IC = $_POST["Dri_IC"];
$Dri_Name = $_POST["Dri_Name"];
$Date_of_Birth = $_POST["Date_of_Birth"];
$Carplate = $_POST["Carplate"];
$Dri_Street_Add = $_POST["Dri_Street_Add"];
$Dri_Postal_Code = $_POST["Dri_Postal_Code"];
$Dri_City = $_POST["Dri_City"];
$Dri_State = $_POST["Dri_State"];
$Dri_Country = $_POST["Dri_Country"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "UPDATE dri_details SET Dri_IC='$Dri_IC', Dri_Name='$Dri_Name', Date_of_Birth='$Date_of_Birth', 
                    Carplate='$Carplate', Dri_Street_Add='$Dri_Street_Add', Dri_Postal_Code='$Dri_Postal_Code', Dri_City='$Dri_City', Dri_State='$Dri_State', Dri_Country='$Dri_Country' 
                    INNER JOIN account_details ON account_details.Acc_ID = dri_details.Dri_ID WHERE account_details.Username='$Username'");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sissssssss", $Username, $Dri_IC, $Dri_Name, $Date_of_Birth, $Carplate, $Dri_Street_Add, $Dri_Postal_Code, $Dri_City, $Dri_State, $Dri_Country);   
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**ProfileUpdate.java**

```
public class ProfileUpdate extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText editTextDriIC, editTextDriName;
private Button buttonUpPro;
private TextView tvDisplay;
SessionManager session;
public static String global_Usernames;
public static String global_AccPass;

private ProgressDialog loading;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_profile);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    // Session class instance
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

    // get name
    String Username = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERNAME);
    global_Usernames = Username;

    // get password
    String Acc_Pass = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_PASSWORD);
    global_AccPass = Acc_Pass;

    final EditText etIdentitycard = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etIdentitycard);
    final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    final EditText etDOB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDOB);
    final EditText etCarplate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCarplate);
    final EditText etAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
    final EditText etPostal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPostal);

    // Get a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView in the layout
    final AutoCompleteTextView etCity = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.etCity);
    // Get the string array
    String[] cities = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.city_array);
    // Create the adapter and set it to the AutoCompleteTextView
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cities);
    etCity.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Get a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView in the layout
    final AutoCompleteTextView etState = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.etState);
    // Get the string array
    String[] states = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.state_array);
    // Create the adapter and set it to the AutoCompleteTextView
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, states);
    etState.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Get a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView in the layout
    final AutoCompleteTextView etCountry = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.etCountry);
    // Get the string array
    String[] country = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
    // Create the adapter and set it to the AutoCompleteTextView
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, country);
    etCountry.setAdapter(adapter);

    final Button buttonUpPro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bUpdate);

    final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateLabel();
        }

        private void updateLabel() {

            //String myFormat = "YYYY/MM/DD"; //In which you need put here
            //DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
            String myFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"; //In which you need put here
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
            //DateFormat sdf = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, Locale.UK);

            etDOB.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
        }

    };

    etDOB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new DatePickerDialog(ProfileUpdate.this, date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });


    buttonUpPro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String Dri_IC = etIdentitycard.getText().toString().trim();
            final String Dri_Name = etName.getText().toString().trim();
            final String Date_of_Birth = etDOB.getText().toString();
            final String Carplate = etCarplate.getText().toString().trim();
            final String Dri_Street_Add = etAddress.getText().toString().trim();
            final String Dri_Postal_Code = etPostal.getText().toString().trim();
            final String Dri_City = etCity.getText().toString().trim();
            final String Dri_State = etState.getText().toString().trim();
            final String Dri_Country = etCountry.getText().toString().trim();

            if (etIdentitycard.getText().toString().matches("") || etName.getText().toString().matches("") || etDOB.getText().toString().matches("") || etAddress.getText().toString().matches("")
                    || etPostal.getText().toString().matches("") || etCity.getText().toString().matches("") || etState.getText().toString().matches("") || etCountry.getText().toString().matches("")) {

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Dri_IC)) {
                    etIdentitycard.setError("You are required to enter your Identification Card Number");
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Dri_Name)) {
                    etName.setError("You are required to enter your Full Name");
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Date_of_Birth)) {
                    etDOB.setError("You are required to enter your Date of Birth");
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Dri_Street_Add)) {
                    etAddress.setError("You are required to enter your House Address");
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Dri_Postal_Code)) {
                    etPostal.setError("You are required to enter your Postal Code");
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Dri_City)) {
                    etCity.setError("You are required to enter City name");
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Dri_State)) {
                    etState.setError("You are required to enter State name");
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Dri_Country)) {
                    etCountry.setError("You are required to enter Country name");
                }

            } else {

                Response.Listener<String> responeListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonRespone = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonRespone.getBoolean("success");

                        /*if (success){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity2.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity2.this.startActivity(intent);
                        }*/

                            if (!success){

                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileUpdate.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Retry")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();

                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(ProfileUpdate.this, getString(R.string.profile_update_success), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                //Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity2.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                //RegisterActivity2.this.startActivity(intent);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                ProfileUpdateRequest profileUpdateRequest = new ProfileUpdateRequest(Dri_IC, Dri_Name, Date_of_Birth, Carplate, Dri_Street_Add, Dri_Postal_Code, Dri_City, Dri_State, Dri_Country, responeListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ProfileUpdate.this);
                queue.add(profileUpdateRequest);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
}
```

**ProfileUpdateRequest.java**

```
public class ProfileUpdateRequest extends StringRequest {

private static final String PROFILEUPDATE_REQUEST = "http://192.168.1.5/UpdateProfile.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public ProfileUpdateRequest(String Dri_IC, String Dri_Name, String Date_of_Birth, String Carplate, String Dri_Street_Add, String Dri_Postal_Code, String Dri_City, String Dri_State, String Dri_Country, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super (Method.POST, PROFILEUPDATE_REQUEST, listener, null);
    Log.i("Getting url info",""+PROFILEUPDATE_REQUEST + " " + Dri_IC + " " + Dri_Name + " " + Date_of_Birth);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("Dri_IC", Dri_IC + "");
    params.put("Dri_Name", Dri_Name);
    params.put("Date_of_Birth", Date_of_Birth);
    params.put("Carplate", Carplate);
    params.put("Dri_Street_Add", Dri_Street_Add);
    params.put("Dri_Postal_Code", Dri_Postal_Code);
    params.put("Dri_City", Dri_City);
    params.put("Dri_State", Dri_State);
    params.put("Dri_Country", Dri_Country);
    params.put("Username", MainActivity.global_Username);

}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
}
```

I'm not sure what went wrong, after i click update on my android, it did not show success or error, and the database did not update as well. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: is your log ( `Log.i("Getting url info",""+PROFILEUP.....` ) in `ProfileUpdateRequest.java` logging anything ?

Comment: @mrid Yes. I'm getting this `I/Getting url info: http://192.168.1.5/UpdateProfile.php 1212121212 qw 2017/09/23`

Comment: what is `null` in `super (Method.POST, PROFILEUPDATE_REQUEST, listener, null);` ?? I don't see `params` being used anywhere ?

Comment: @mrid I'm sorry but i do not know what is `null` for but i follow a tutorial that is use for register a user then i use back the same code just for update a user, i'm not entirely sure that whether or not i should use back the same code.